# Fonts on my iMac randomly become blurry (badly anti-aliased) until restart

Tags: macos, imac

I have a late-2009 iMac with Yosemite 10.10.2.

Recently, I've noticed that some system fonts randomly become blurry, as though there's a problem with the anti-aliasing. This affects:

- The OS X Menu bar
- The right-click context menu
- The side-bar in the Finder window
- Etc.

In this screenshot - you can see how the text in my browser window looks sharp, but the right-click context menu items are blurry:

[image: Blurry fonts in the right-click context menu]

They are not blurry when I restart. At some point, usually with in a few hours, and not after any specific, repeatable event - they become blurry. (I've never noticed ***exactly*** when it happens. All of a sudden, when I stop focusing on my work, I notice that they're blurry.

If I restart the Mac, they become sharp again, but only temporarily.

I've never played around with any settings that might have caused this change (e.g, I haven't changed LCD font smoothing or anything). And I haven't replaced the graphics card. In short - I haven't changed anything that I'm aware of.

Thanks in advance for any advice or insight!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should change your font smoothing strength  and contrast settings. Many other people are having the same problem. Check out [this](http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/27/change-font-smoothing-text-os-x-yosemite/) link for information on how to do this